# SQLite Database Encryption C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, encryption, ormlite-servicestack

I'm using ORMLite and SQLite for my ORM and database in a WPF application. The way I am currently encrypting my data is by using an AES 256 function that encrypts each individual string in the database. This is becoming messy, and causing me to write about 50 lines of code I shouldn't need.

Is there a way of encrypting a SQLite database within C# using .net, ORMLite or SQLite?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you encrypt the entire sqlite database file then on startup decrypt it with your AES key and write it to a temp file at [Path.GetTempFileName()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) and have Sqlite connect to the temporary decrypted Sqlite database.

Then when the Application exists encrypt the file contents and overwrite the existing `sqlite.db.encrypted`.

If needed ServiceStack has a useful [AesUtils](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/b5e6947fa60532a2147de36d7e11213a5f37dfcb/src/ServiceStack.Client/CryptUtils.cs#L198) class that provides convenient API's to encrypt and decrypt arbitrary bytes.